# How to make Viméo buttons bigger on smartphone?

Tags: css, controls, vimeo, smartphone

I have a problem with Vimeo player integration. On smartphones, because the resolution is high for a little screen space, the control buttons appear incredibly tiny.

Here is what I have for a 6,5 cm large (2.3 inches large) screen. The fullscreen button is only a 1mm large (0.3 inches), impossible to target with a finger:

[image]

Is there a known solution to that?

I tried to explore the CSS of the vimeo controls (that I could modify for smartphones), but it's complicated and intricate on several levels, and before I would like to be sure there isn't an easy existing solution – the possibility of a big separated fullscreen button would also work.

Finding absolutely nothing about this problem on the net, I wonder if I don't miss something obvious...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it of it is a cross-origin iframe.

Comment: Ho... What would be the alternative?